# Adapting paged data to Java Stream

Tags: java, mysql, java-stream, jooq, paging

I want to take paged data (from a DB) and adapt it into a lazy-loading Java Stream so that the clients of my DAO don't need to worry about page indexes, offsets, and so on.

My setup is as follows: I have a DAO method that can fetch pages of data from a DB. Specifically, it uses [MySQL SEEK](https://blog.jooq.org/faster-sql-paging-with-jooq-using-the-seek-method/) to do paging. I.e., to fetch page 5, you need to provide the method with the last record of page 4.

What is the simplest way of adapting this style of paging to a Java Stream? For my use case libraries are fine, but frameworks (Spring, Androidx, etc) are not.

### My implementation

I've written my own implementation as follows. (`Field`, `Record`, and `Result` are JOOQ classes)

```java
public abstract class PagedSeekIterator<K> implements Iterator<Record> {

   private K lastId = null;
   private boolean done = false;
   private Iterator<Record> currentIterator = null;
   private final Field<K> idField;

   public PagedSeekIterator(Field<K> idField) {
      this.idField = idField;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean hasNext() {
      if (done) {
         return false;
      }
      try {
         if (currentIterator == null) {
            // first call. Do init
            currentIterator = fetchWithSeek(lastId).iterator();
            return hasNext();
         }
         if (currentIterator.hasNext()) {
            return true;
         } else {
            // current page is read through. Fetch next page
            Result<Record> res = fetchWithSeek(lastId);
            if (res.isEmpty()) {
               // we're done here
               done = true;
               currentIterator = null;
               return false;
            } else {
               // next page looks good
               currentIterator = res.iterator();
               return true;
            }
         }
      } catch (SQLException e) {
         throw new SqlRuntimeException("Failed to fetch page", e);
      }
   }

   @Override
   public Record next() {
      if (!hasNext()) {
         throw new NoSuchElementException("We're done here.");
      }

      Record rec = currentIterator.next();
      lastId = rec.get(idField);
      return rec;
   }

   // lastId will be null on the first call
   protected abstract Result<Record> fetchWithSeek(K lastId) throws SQLException;
}
```

And then adapting to a stream is conveniently taken care of by Guava:

```java
Streams.stream(new PagedSeekIterator<Long>(Actions.ACTION.ID){
  // override fetchWithSeek()
});
// returns a lazy Stream<Record>
```

My implementation works, but I can't help but feel like I'm reinventing the wheel here.

### Other things I've tried

I've also tried looking into [AndroidX Paging](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/v3-overview), but using it outside an Android/Kotlin context is painful and I've found it adds more complexity than it alleviates for my plain Java project.

Comment: There's nothing like this in jOOQ itself, if that's what your question is about...

Answer (score 0):

Here are the solutions by my library [abacus-jdbc](https://github.com/landawn/abacus-jdbc).

1. If you want to return a `stream` with all records(pages) by one query and split by stream api:

   ```
   JdbcUtil.prepareQuery(dataSource, sqlQuery)
         //.setParameters(...); // if needed
         stream(YourEntityClass.class); //.split(pageSize)
   ```
2. If you want to return a `stream` for one specific page (by seek?)

   ```
   final String query = "select * from yourTable where someIdColumn > ? order by someIdColumn limit pageSize";
   JdbcUtil.prepareQuery(dataSource, query)
         .setLong(1, lastPageEndId);
         stream(YourEntityClass.class); // or stream(rowMapper);
   ```
3. If you want to return a `stream`. Each element in the stream is one `page`(a list of records) which is loaded by executing query once:

   ```
    final String query = "select * from yourTable where someIdColumn > ? order by someIdColumn limit pageSize";
    JdbcUtil.queryByPage(dataSource, query, pageSize, (stmt, ret) -> stmt.setLong(1, ret == null ? startId : ret.get(ret.size() - 1).getId());
   ```

Comment: That's cool. Will your lib internally page through data, or do one select and then stream that?

Comment: Updated answer. you can just query one once  for all pages or query once for each page.  I just have a quick look at the code in your question. it seems you ran db query for each record, not each page. I think it's going to be very slow. please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: So my implementation uses MYSQL SEEK which effectively pages. But nevermind that. I'm looking for a generic page-to-stream Java library that can page over anything and transform it into a stream.